# Arthur C. Clarke's Bibliography

Tags: short-stories, arthur-c-clarke

Having read a few stories (reading Rendezvous with Rama currently) I have (of course) become a huge fan of Sir Arthur. So I have decided to systematically go through all of his scifi works.

First question, does "The Collected Stories of Arthur C. Clarke" include all of his short stories? Are there any that are missing? if yes then which ones?

Second question, the novels are easy. But are there any comprehensive collections of his novellas and novelettes> I guess the bigger question is, what is the best strategy here for the novellas and novelettes? What books/collections I should buy so that I have the least number of total books with the least amount of overlap between them and yet have them be exhaustive so that they contain all of the novellas and novelettes? And if there are any audiobooks for novellas/novelettes that would be ideal.

Thanks!

Comment: Lots of questions in one. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Collected_Stories_of_Arthur_C._Clarke) answers one of them, saying "The Collected Stories of Arthur C. Clarke, (..) is a collection of _almost all_ science fiction stories ..." (emphasis mine). Wouldn't know how to get the answers to your other questions.

Comment: But it isn't clear on which ones are missing. It only mentions one. There are only two questions really and I asked them together here because they are related. I am hoping that a die hard Clarke fan will turn up here sooner or later.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I see two of them. A question regarding Clarke's scifi works doesn't belong here at scifi.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, there are several stories missing from "The Collected Stories of Arthur C. Clarke". Here's a list of the missing stories, possibly incomplete:

- The Fate of Fu Manchu (1935)
- At the Mountains of Murkiness (1940)
- When the Twerms Came (1972)
- Tales from the "White Hart", 1990: The Jet-Propelled Time Machine (1990)
- Hibernaculum 46 (with Stephen Baxter) (2000)
- Time Gentleman Please (with Stephen Baxter) (2007)

Comment: Comparing the content of "The Collected Stories of Arthur C. Clarke" with the ISFDB is tedious, because the short fiction section on ISFDB's Clarke page contains not only short stories, but other items as well, like novel excerpts and fragments. So I think the list above is more useful than a mere reference to ISFDB. – "The Fate of Fu Manchu" was first published in Huish Magazine in 1935, and republished in "Childhood Ends: The Earliest Writings of Arthur C. Clarke", Portentous Press, 1996. Some information on this can be found [here](http://hq.abaa.org/books/antiquarian/news_fly?code=97).

Answer (score 4):

Well it turns out that all of his short stories, novellas, and novelettes are included in [Collected Stories](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0312878605). There is only one short story called "When the Twerms Came" (1972) which is missing from that collection for some reason. So in print form, just that one book contains everything by Clarke except his novels.

In audiobook form however, [The Collected Stories of Arthur C. Clarke](http://www.audible.com/pd/ref=sr_1_1?asin=B002V1ONBS&qid=1358499129&sr=1-1) was published but only half of it was published. So if you want to listen to this collection, then instead get the [five volume version](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1407439421).